# Creating a redirect page php that handles multiple destinations?

Tags: php, redirect

I have a website with about 50 pages, each sends the visitor to a different external url, currently with a direct link to the external domain.

I'm rebuilding the website, and want to have the visitor pass first through an internal redirect page.

Instead of building 50 different redirect pages, how can I create one redirect page that would handle all these 50 different destinations?

I guess I can transform the links into

```
http://example.com/redirect.php?destination=[1/2/3/4/.../50]
```

But how do I define (in the easiest way) on the redirect.php,
**the matching external URL for each of these destination numbers?**

preferably with some simple .txt file, like

```
1 http://external-1.com/
2 http://external-2.com/
.
.
50 http://external-50.com/
```

Comment: try a case switch, or an array

Comment: Hi, Could you give me an example? I'm a newbie in php :(

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
<?php
$destinations = array(
1=> 'http://urlone',
2=> 'http://urltwo',
3=> 'http://urlthree',
);
$destination = $_GET['destination'];
if(in_array($destination, $destinations)){
    header("location:".$destinations[$destination]);
}
?>
```